# How to define a function of variable in NumPy

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to define a `f(x)` function with `x` being a variable (not yet a number) using `numpy` so that I can use it somewhere else and then evaluate at some point. for example:

```py
f(x) = A sin(k x)
```

I want to define `f`, and then later define `A`, `k` and `x`. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: have you  read a basic python introduction?

Comment: @hpaulj yes I know I can use functions via def and then define numpy functions in them but I would want to recieve functions from user later with symbols etc...

Comment: `numpy` is a numeric, array, package written python.  It does not add any syntax.  `sympy` is a symbolics package - but it too has to conform to python syntax,

Comment: Please clarify in the question whether you want to return a function, a closure or to parse user input into a function at runtime and add the code you can provide yourself for this specific problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can make a lambda function:

```py
import numpy as np
f = lambda a,k,x: a * np.sin(k*x)

print(f(2, 2, np.pi / 4)) # Prints 2.0 == 2 * sin(2 * pi / 4)
```

Comment: Thank you I knew this and  I just wanted to know if there are numpy codes for it. for example in mathemtica  we define f[x_] := expression.. to define a mathematical function

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Why is `numpy` specifically necessary here?

Comment: To be clear, I'm not a frequent user of Mathematica -- if there's any specific syntax constructs you're looking for, I'm happy to help, but I ask that you spell them out for me.

Comment: Thank you I used your code + some iteration to get the result I need

Comment: @AmirE as hpaulj above noted, for mathematica-like functionality you may be more looking for `sympy` than `numpy`